# No valid certificates were found on this smart card

Tags: windows-10, smartcard, client-certificates, digital-certificate, credential-manager

I'm using **Yubikey4** as my smart card with my **StartCom Class 1 login certificate**. My problem is: **windows don't want to use this card**.

Windows credential manager: "No valid certificates were found on this smart card".

Microsoft office doesn't see this card.

Windows VPN: "A certificate could not be found that can be used with this Extensible Authentication Protocol."

Keepass2 (RSA Certificate Key Provider plugin - uses windows security): "No cerficiate available. No certificates meets the application criteria." (of course tested with RSA certificate too).

**My certificate details:**

Key Usage: Digital Signature, Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment (b0)

Enhanced Key Usage: Client Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2), Secure Email (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.4)

Public key parameters: ECDH_P384

**From device manager:**

Smart card name: "Identity Device (NIST SP 800-73 [PIV])"

Smart card reader name: "Microsoft Usbccid Smartcard Reader (WUDF)"

Is there any key usage required for smart card usage?

Answer (score 1):

Your Device Manager indicates that you are using the Microsoft Minidriver for the smartcard. According to the [Yubikey Basic Troubleshooting Guide](https://support.yubico.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015654900-Smart-Card-Basic-Troubleshooting) this problem can be caused by using these minidrivers for the smartcard rather than the Yubico minidrivers.

You can install the driver following this guide: https://support.yubico.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015654560-Deploying-the-YubiKey-Minidriver-to-Workstations-and-Servers.